# How does local_assigns work in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I've been googling around about this and can't find the right path. I'm working on a Rails app that is using a method called local_assigns. This appears to be something in Rails or a gem, and not specific to my app, but it's used for rendering a partial in different contexts, such as this:

```
<% if local_assigns[:custom_name] %>
  <li><%= custom_name %></li>
<% else %>
```

or also this:

```
<%= render "discussions/complementary/#{local_assigns[:action] || params[:action]}" %>
```

Is this is Rails method? Where can I find more documentation about this?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

`local_assigns` is a Rails view helper method that you can check whether this partial has been provided with local variables or not.

Here you render a partial with some values, the `headline` and `person` will become accessible with predefined value.

```
<%= render "shared/header", { :headline => "Welcome", :person => person } %>
```

In `shared/header` view:

```
Headline: <%= headline %>
First name: <%= person.first_name %>
```

Here is how you check these variables has passed in or not:

```
<% if local_assigns.has_key? :headline %>
  Headline: <%= headline %>
<% end %>
```

Check this document for more detail on the section [**rails 3.2 Passing local variables to sub templates**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/classes/ActionView/Base.html#label-Passing+local+variables+to+sub+templates).

Updated rails 7 link: [ActionView/Base.html](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Base.html#class-ActionView::Base-label-Passing+local+variables+to+sub+templates)

Comment: When linking to Rails Guides, it would help to include the Rails version in the URL. That link for Rails 4.2.0 doesn't mention local_assigns that I can tell.

Comment: Rather than `<% if local_assigns.has_key? :headline %>`,  why can't we just do `<% if headline %>`?

Comment: @MikeC this is because if headline is undefined (i.e. not passed to the partial) you'll get an NameError "undefined local variable or method..." raised rather than a falsey value.

Comment: Why cannot you just do `if defined? headline` then?

Comment: @EricAnderson, because raising an error can save your life when debugging :).

Comment: The guide also states `"Testing using defined? headline will not work. This is an implementation restriction."`

Comment: @EricAnderson I'd like to add that `local_assigns` is much more explicit and clear when used in a partial. I ran into a confusing situation where I was testing for a local in a partial by the name of `format`. Using `defined?( format )` would always pass because `format` is a Ruby method for String formatting. It was at this point that we decided to always use `local_assigns` when testing for the presence of locals in partials. I suggest you and yours adopt the same. It might save you minutes to hours of heartache in the future.

Comment: Interesting, but since Rails5 documentation changed from `Testing using defined? headline will not work. This is an implementation restriction.` to `Alternatively, you could also use defined? headline to first check if the variable has been assigned before using it.`